# Deserialize a json to find which object maps Android Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, gson

In my application i use Sockets.The income messages from socket are jsons and i want to map each json to each according object.

For example i have the json

```
{ "er": { "i":"1001", "m":"message text" } }
```

which matches the data class

```
data class Error(
    val er: Er
)

data class Er(
    val i: String,
    val m: String
)
```

but i also have a json like

```
{
   "statusCode":200, "body":{ 
      "au":{
         "a": 44,
      }
    }
}
```

which is the data class

```
data class Authentication(
    val body: Body,
    val statusCode: Int
)
 
data class Body(
    val au: Au
)
data class Au(
    val a: Int
)
```

By default i know that my API will never have the same kind of jsons!

So i tried to do something like

```
try {
   val thing = Gson().fromJson(mJson, Error::class.java)
   // This json is Error type of object. Do something with it
catch(e: JsonSyntaxException) {
   // This json is not Error object. Maybe its  Authentication
   // Proceed to check another object
}
```

However i noticed that no exception happens and `thing` is an `Error` object with null fields.

Is there any mechanism or library that can find in which object a json maps?

Comment: Can you post an example JSON and the corresponding class?

Comment: You can imagine any json and any class...this has to be a generic function

Comment: You want library to automagically figure out which object type was encoded in JSON (without provding it desired type on deserialization)? How you imagine that? Consider you have two classes `data class Class1(val str: String)` `data class Class2(val str: String)` and `{"str": "123"}` as JSON. How it should be deserialized? As instance of `Class1` or `Class2`?

Comment: Or you want it to be strict on deserialization and throw an exception when provided JSON doesn't match with specified type?

Comment: I have edited the question in case its more understandable now!

Comment: Is it possible to add extra field to JSONs (so that they become `{"type": "Error", "er": { "i":"1001", "m":"message text" } }` and `{"type": "Authentication", "statusCode":200, "body":{ "au":{"a": 44, }}}`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve this with [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library.
But at first you need to narrow down set of possible deserialized types to a polymorphic class hierarchy.
In most general case it could be an interface:

```kotlin
interface AuthOrError
```

All types, that may be a result of deserialization, should implement it; and all classes involved in deserialization should be marked with `@Serializable` annotation:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Authentication(val body: Body, val statusCode: Int) : AuthOrError

@Serializable
data class Body(val au: Au)

@Serializable
data class Au(val a: Int)

@Serializable
data class Error(val er: Er) : AuthOrError

@Serializable
data class Er(val i: String, val m: String)
```

But deserialization library is not a psychic. There should be some unique distinguishing feature in JSON content, so that deserialization library could map it to particular type.

The simplest way to achieve it - is to add `type` field with FQN of target type value to each JSON object (like `{"type": "Error", "er": { "i":"1001", "m":"message text" } })`. After that you need to register all possible values of this field (an exact set of types, implementing this interface, that could be a deserialization result):

```kotlin
val authOrErrorModule = SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(AuthOrError::class) {
        subclass(Authentication::class)
        subclass(Error::class)
    }
}
```

Then pass it to `serializersModule` property and magic happens:

```kotlin
when (val thing = Json{serializersModule = authOrErrorModule}.decodeFromString<AuthOrError>(mJson)) {
    is Authentication -> {
        println(thing.statusCode) //smart casted as Authentication
    }
    is Error -> {
        println(thing.er) //smart casted as Error
    }
}
```

If it's impossible to modify JSON format, then you need to create your own deserializer and manually define algorithm for choosing type (more precisely, its (de)serializer) based on JSON content. For instance, in this case, you may say "if JSON has `statusCode` field, then it must be an `Authentication`, otherwise it is `Error`":

```kotlin
object AuthOrErrorSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<AuthOrError>(AuthOrError::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement) = when {
        "statusCode" in element.jsonObject -> Authentication.serializer()
        else -> Error.serializer()
    }
}
```

Then pass it as a serializer and voila:

```kotlin
when (val thing = Json.decodeFromString(AuthOrErrorSerializer, mJson)) {
    is Authentication -> {
        println(thing.statusCode)// smart casted as Authentication
    }
    is Error -> {
        println(thing.er) // smart casted as Error
    }
}
```